# Read JSON file from local storage when Internet is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I am populating html table with Json Data from Internet server and also I have  json file with name example.json placed inside same folder where index.html is placed.
I would like to load json file and populate the html table from Online Server if Internet is available and also overwrite the previous data from example.json file if there is new changes in json file in server and load from local storage when Internet is not available.

Ps: I have added all the library of css and js inside the same directory also.

So Far I'm using below code for my html

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h1>Json</h1>
      <br/>

      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
        <tr>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>Time</th>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var employee_data = '';
    if (localStorage.myJSON !== undefined) {
      var myJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.myJSON);
      employee_data += '<tbody>';
      $.each(myJSON, function(key, value) {
        employee_data += '<tr>';
        employee_data += '<td>' + value.class + '</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>' + value.time + '</td>';

        employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      employee_data += '</tbody>';
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
    }

    employee_data = '';

    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8qktd", function(data) {
      $("#yourtableid tbody").remove();

      localStorage.setItem(myJSON, JSON.stringify(data));
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        employee_data += '<tr>';
        employee_data += '<td>' + value.class + '</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>' + value.time + '</td>';

        employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

    });

  });
</script>
```

and my Json File is

```js
var myJSON= [

    {
    "id":"1",    
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
    
},
{


    "id":"2",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"3",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"4",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"5",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"6",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"7",
  "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"8",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"9",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"10",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"11",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"12",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
}

]
```

and next thing is place a button which OnClick will getJson file from server and compare with local storage, and if Both are same then display message box with text " your Data is upto Date" else show " Please update your Table and show a update button on message box , which will refresh the page thus will load the table with new data and also overwrite the old data in local storage"

Is is possible, I'm expecting impossible.

Any help??

Comment: Well for a start you are using `jQuery` and linking to the library via their website. If you don't have internet connection how are you going to get the required library? You should download the `jQuery` library and link to it locally. You will want to do the same for `bootstrap` and anything else you are trying to use on the internet.

Comment: That is not the problem, I have already added those library inside the folder, but here to show an example I have added url instead. I will reedit my Question again. Thanks for your concerns.